# How to send an email with a link to an auto-populated form in MailChimp?

Tags: google-forms, mailchimp

MailChimp always appends the "update subscription preferences" link at the bottom of an email, which links to a page that is auto-populated with the subscriber's name and email.

Is there a way in MailChimp to create a *custom* form that is auto-populated with subscriber info?

For example, we're looking to send out a link to a form for our subscribers to sign up for a program we're running.  Normally we'd use something like Google Forms, but since MailChimp already knows their names and emails, it would be nice if there's a way that the link to the form would be auto-populated with the subscriber's information so they don't need to re-enter it.